# how to get the uri value after record the video in android

Tags: android, uri

Hi i am new android i trying to get the uri of saved a video in the sd card.i want the uri like this format.content//media/external/video/media/18576 actully i m geting like this /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4 this is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
  private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);


    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);

  }
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view

            previewCapturedImage();
            System.out.print(videoPath);

        //    tv1.setText(String.valueOf((videoPath))); 

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // video successfully recorded
            // preview the recorded video
             String s = data.getData().getPath();

            previewVideo();
            System.out.print(fileUri);
            tv1.setText(s);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
                content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoPath);

                ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
                Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ""+uri,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title_text");
                sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
                //File newFile = new File(path_var);
            //  sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Where you want to share?"));
```